# Python, how to combine integer matrix to a list

Tags: python, numpy

say I have a matrix : `a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`. How can I combine it to `b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`?

Many thanks

Comment: `b = numpy.hstack(a)`

Comment: `import itertools; list(itertools.chain(*a))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists), [Flattening a shallow list in Python \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python), [concatenating sublists python \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142101/concatenating-sublists-python), etc.

Comment: Duplicate of [how-to-unnest-a-nested-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860476/how-to-unnest-a-nested-list)

Comment: Is `a` a list of lists or a numpy array?  Why the numpy tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = numpy.hstack(a)
list(b)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution if you have numpy installed.

Comment: I assumed he wants that based on the tags of the question. The other solutions work too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the most beautiful, but it works:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [sub_thing for thing in a for sub_thing in thing]
print(b)
```

Prints:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 0):

Without using numpy:

```
#make the empty list b
b=[]
for row in a:#go trough the matrix a
    for value in row: #for every value
        b.append(value) #python is fun and easy
```

Comment: This is not the most efficient solution (that would be using a package like numpy) but easy to understand and works without additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to combine integer matrix could be using the `itertools` `chain`.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)
```

prints:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 0):

using numpy:

`list(np.array(a).flatten())`